# Invoking browsers with Baseclass.Contrib.Specflow in C# using Browser.Current

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, baseclass-contrib

I'm currently trying to use Selenium Grid 2 to run automation tests on multiple browsers. During my research I came across using Baseclass.Contrib.Specflow which enables me to use the browsers as tags in the feature files without having to declare it in my  main driver class. The problem I have is that one of the blogs I read had the following as the set up code

```
[SetUp]
public void Test_Setup(){
CurrentDriver = Browser.Current;}
```

My app config file looks contains the following:

```
   <components>
  <!-- <component name="Firefox" type="OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver, WebDriver" service="OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, WebDriver" instance-scope="per-dependency">
  </component>-->
  <component name="Firefox" 
             type="Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.RemoteWebDriver, Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.SpecFlowPlugin" 
             service="OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, WebDriver" 
            instance-scope="per-dependency">
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="url" value=" http://localhost/wd/hub" />
      <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
    </parameters>
  </component>
  <component name="Safari" type="Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.RemoteWebDriver, Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.SpecFlowPlugin" service="OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver, WebDriver" instance-scope="per-dependency">
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="url" value=" http://localhost/wd/hub" />
      <parameter name="desiredCapabilities" value="Chrome" />
    </parameters>
  </component>
```

I get an error when I try to run the script using the above Setup method.

Error:

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key was not present in the dictionary

The blog I got this solution from doesn't seem to answer questions regarding to this so I'm a bit desperate. This will basically allow me to to the following on the feature file and get tests to run based on the tag

```
@Browser:Firefox
@Browser:Chrome
```

Hope this is enough information to give me advice.

Comment: Which blog?  http://www.radicalgeek.co.uk/Post/14/acceptance-test-driven-development-of-an-mvc-web-application-using-specflow-and-selenium-webdriver.  I've got the same issue as yourself, though things seemed to run to a certain point.

Comment: Yes it's the same post. How did you get things to run for you?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are making here is that you are annotating your entire feature file with the tag `@Browser`.

`Baseclass.Contrib.Specflow` allows you to annotate *scenarios* with scenario supporting Browsers. Therefore, you have to annotate each scenario.

If you don't do that, there is no Current Browser set for that test and trying to access `Browser.Current` will throw `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException`.

You know you're doing it right when the generated Unit Tests will include the Browser name as part of the unit test name like

```
<Test Name> on <Browser> with: <parameters>
```

Example:

```
@Browser:IE
@Browser:Chrome
@Browser:Firefox
Scenario Outline: Add Two Numbers
>Given I navigated to / using
And I have entered <summandOne> into summandOne calculator
And I have entered <summandTwo> into summandTwo calculator
When I press add
Then the result should be <result> on the screen
Scenarios:
| summandOne| summandTwo|result|
| 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 |
```